# using dsift of the vlfeat library with cv::Mat

Tags: c++, c, opencv, computer-vision, vlfeat

I am currently trying to use the dsift-algorithm of the vlfeat-lib. But no matter with which values I create the filter (sample step, bin size), it returns the same number of keypoints for every frame during an execution (consecutive frames are different, from a camera). The documentation on C or C++ usage is very thin, and I could not find any good examples for these languages..
Here is the relevant code:

```
// create filter
vlf = vl_dsift_new_basic(320, 240, 1, 3);

// transform image in cv::Mat to float vector
std::vector<float> imgvec;
for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; ++i){
  for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; ++j){
    imgvec.push_back(img.at<unsigned char>(i,j) / 255.0f);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  }
}
// call processing function of vl
vl_dsift_process(vlf, &imgvec[0]);

// echo number of keypoints found
std::cout << vl_dsift_get_keypoint_num(vlf) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it returns the same number of keypoints for every frame during an
>   execution

This is normal with **dense** SIFT implementation since the number of extracted keypoints only depends on input geometrical parameters[1], i.e. step and image size.

See the [documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/dsift.html):

> The feature frames (keypoints) are indirectly specified by the sampling steps (`vl_dsift_set_steps`) and the sampling bounds (`vl_dsift_set_bounds`).

[1]: `vl_dsift_get_keypoint_num` returns `self->numFrames` that is only updated by `_vl_dsift_update_buffers` which uses geometrical information only (bounds, steps and bin sizes).

Comment: Yup. Dense sift extracts descriptors based on a fixed grid. This gives the same number of descriptors per image.